# Validate names against Name Constraints extension of a X509Certificate CA

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have a CA Certificate parsed as `X509Certificate` object which may or may not have [Name Constraints](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/x509-name-constraints-certificate-extension-all-you-should-know.aspx) extension.

Before I sign a new certificate using this CA certificate, I want to manually verify that given a hostname or IP address will be allowed by the CA. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I could see the JDK has decent APIs for this, they are all internal. So I ended up using Bouncy Castle.

```
  public boolean validateAgainstNamingConstraints(X509Certificate certificate, GeneralName name) {
    NameConstraints nameConstraints = null;
    try {
      nameConstraints = NameConstraints.getInstance(
          JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(certificate.getExtensionValue(Extension.nameConstraints.getId())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.warn("Failed to parse name constraint. Skipping validation. {}", e.getMessage());
      return true;
    }

    if (nameConstraints == null) {
      return true;
    }

    var nameConstraintValidator = new PKIXNameConstraintValidator();
    if (nameConstraints.getPermittedSubtrees() != null) {
      nameConstraintValidator.intersectPermittedSubtree(nameConstraints.getPermittedSubtrees());
    }

    if (nameConstraints.getExcludedSubtrees() != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nameConstraints.getExcludedSubtrees().length; i++) {
        nameConstraintValidator.addExcludedSubtree(nameConstraints.getExcludedSubtrees()[i]);
      }
    }

    try {
      nameConstraintValidator.checkPermitted(name);
      nameConstraintValidator.checkExcluded(name);
      return true;
    } catch (NameConstraintValidatorException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

How to use:

```
validateAgainstNamingConstraints(certificate, new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "test.google.com"))
validateAgainstNamingConstraints(certificate, new GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress, "192.168.111.1"))
```